# Change Outlook message class name without form region

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2007, outlook-2010, classname

I'd like to change a message's class name - such as `IPM.Note.MyName`.

However I don't want to change it's form region.

In order to change the class name I need to register it somehow - How can I do that, since I don't have any form region?

Thanks,

Nili

Answer (score 0):

You can change the class ([`MessageClass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.messageclass.aspx)) without defining a custom form region - so long as the class Name starts with `IPM.Note` it will be treated just like a regular message item.

If you want custom form regions - you would have to add them by following the [`IFormRegionFactory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.outlook.iformregionfactory.aspx) interface, but this isn't necessary.

Comment: I get behavior as if the class is not defined. Is it possible to define it somewhere? I once saw a CFG file that contained a class name. Thanks again, Nili

Comment: Please describe the behavior you get. Outlook should handle your custom class just as it would an existing `IPM.Note` - as long as you prefix it properly.